# HTML Previous date validation

Tags: javascript, html

im getting a problem with my code. 
I want it so if the user was to selects yesterday or any previous date it should give an alert box telling the user #Please enter a vlid date'

When i select yesterdays date it gives me an alert message.
When i select todays date it gives me an alert message.
When i select tomorrows date it gives me an alert message.

Why does it give me an alert message when I select today's message??

```
<input type='date' onchange="validateDate()" id='mydate'></input>

<script>

    function validateDate() {
    var userdate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydate").value);
    var today = new Date();

       if(userdate < today){

            alert('Your message');
       }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the date input is only setting the date itself and leaving the hours, minutes and seconds as 00:00:00. Therefore, the output of `new Date()`, which includes this additional data, will always be greater than the output of the date input for the current day.

To overcome this, you can use a different value to reflect today's time, which like the value from the date input will only contain the year, month, day, and the timezone offset.

It goes as follows:

```
var today = new Date();
var todayForComparison = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 0, -today.getTimezoneOffset());
```

Now, use "todayForComparison" in your if statement instead of the original "today" variable.

Answer (score 1):

The date value returned by `new Date(document.getElementById("mydate").value)` has time as `00:00`. That's why when you select today's date, you are able to see the alert.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a date with empty time (00:00) with a full dateTime (xx:xx).
You should remove the dateTime before comparing dates.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xnquczae/)
First Convert user value to Date Format and use getTime function() to compare there are many method better then this and best you can use moment.js

```
 var userDate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydate").value);
    var today = new Date();
    if (today.getTime()>userDate.getTime()) {
        alert("invalid date");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m4dqbqb/), i added an event listener from js:

```
var el = document.getElementById("mydate");
el.onchange = onChangeDate;

function onChangeDate(e){
    if(new Date(el.value) < new Date()){
        alert("invalid date");
    }
}
```